# Stellar Core Data

Tags: stellar-core

Where can I download the full Stellar transactions and payments history? I have seen already that I can download one page at a time in the Stellar Website, but id like to do a full download since its inception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a [stellar-core](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/admin.html) server configured with CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true (otherwise it will only get the last CATCHUP_RECENT ledgers) which will download all the raw history from configured archives.

Then you'll need to install a [stellar-horizon](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon) server and make it [ingest](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/admin.md#ingesting-live-stellar-core-data) all data from your stellar-core instance - which means it will process all the raw data from stellar-core into a more conveniently accessible database scheme.

Finally you can find all transaction data in your local horizon database (usually postgres) and also access it via your local horizons api.